# How can I remove the following warning?

Tags: makefile

I have got the following warning while building my code:

> gcc   -o uartsim.exe xtmpmain.o uartsim.o fiber_driver.o xtmp_options.o getopt.o D:\usr\xtensa\XtDev
>   ToolsDE\install\tools\RB-2008.4-win32\XtensaTools\lib\iss\xtmp.lib
>   mt -V manifest uartsim.exe.manifest '-f outputresource:uartsim.exe;1'
>   mt V2.3, Corinna Vinschen, Apr 19 2004
>   make: *** No rule to make target `', needed by`all'.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

"It means simply that the build tools want to build an object file but can't find all of the source files needed to do it. Consequently the tools will attempt to make the missing files but will then discover they don't know how to do that, hence the error message about not having a rule to "make target". The message can happen for a number of reasons."

So make sure that all of the files needed to build your tree of dependencies actually exists.

Here are some links on the web that should help:

1. http://www.newlc.com/en/forum/whats-no-rule-make-target-error-actually-means
2. http://www.google.com/search?q="No+rule+to+make+target"